# Prevent a Retrofit request when a proxy is being used

Tags: android, proxy, retrofit2

Im using retrofit 2 + OkHttp in my android app.

There are some apps like **BBVA** that when a proxy is being used it doesnt makes any request and closes the user session, I can see my retrofit requests uisng a proxy like **Charles**.

The behavior I want to do is: if a proxy is being used. block / cancel any Retrofit 2 requests. is this possible with Retrofit?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to take several actions to protect your app:
   - Validate root, Certificate pinning (https) and Obfuscate code